# javascript closures vs class instances

Tags: javascript, oop, closures

This question is more about theoretical programming rather than practic.

I've been reading about closures in javascript. They are, to put it simply, a function with a set of variables accessible only by the function, not by copies that can be made of the function. Each function has its own **var a**.

However, I see it working exactly as instances of the same class, each with its own members/properties. The method of an instance can access only the **var a** in that instance.

Do closures accomplish something that OOP can't do? Or, at least, something with cleaner code, or another advantage, when using closures?

Sorry to put that way, but I see people talking about closures as if it where one of the greatest things javascript has to offer... but I see it only as a side effect of creating a function whose scope does not vanish. Am I wrong?

***EDIT***

As some people think this question has only opinion based answers, I'll reword the question so that the discussion becomes concrete:

What can closures do that cannot be done with only the OOP javascript offers?

Comment: Javascript doesn't really have classes (in ES5), it has prototypes and scope , and enclosing something in a certain scope, and then for instance using it in a function defined in a lower scope, creates a closure where a variable declared in the parent scope is still available etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found (or maybe I couldn't figure out this in the past, even if I've already read about it) an advantage of closures.

When one uses the OOP in javascript, there is no way to make private variables (as a lone wolf programmer, never needed them). The members of an object are always accessible, that is, always on the scope.

But closures make variables accessible only for code in the scope they are defined. Any attempt to use the name of the variable outside the scope will reach other variable (if defined) that has the same name on that scope. And there is no way to get inside the scope of these variables to get/set them, **unless** said scope offers get/set methods to outside scope. These methods have access to the variable and can be called from the "outside world". A way to create private variables an getter/setter methods!

Another advantage is to never mess with outside variables that have the same name, as stated before, when inside the closure's scope.

This is the so called "encapsulation" that can be achieved with closures rather than with normal javascript OOP.

Comment: I'm learning JS and I'm really confused about objects and closures just like you. +1 Nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I use classes, or instantiatable objects when i need multiple instances of something, and usually function closures for when there is only ever going to be one instance, just to keep lots of internal vars private.

Closures aren't just an alternative for a class though, "closing over" variables from outer scopes is something that is used a lot in js.